# Can I combine channels or edit them at the same time?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Using Blender VSE I have two channels, an audio channel and a movie channel.

I plan to be splitting them up and reordering the splits - nothing too complex. However, with the audio and the video in two separate channels, that's twice as much work for me to do.

Is there a way for me to merge channels together so I only have to apply these edits one, or a way for me to apply edits to both channels at the same time?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can select the audio and video strips and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+  <kbd>G</kbd> to group them together (essentially combining the channels).

Now you can make your cuts and reorganize them.

This combined strip is called a ***[Meta Strip](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/vse/sequencer/meta.html)***, and by pressing the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key you can dive into the Meta Strip to edit the contents inside of it.